# Day and night cycle won't work (graphics.py)

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

Whenever I type n for night, it only plays the day cycle. I'm generally new to python and would appreciate help.

```
userinput = input("Is it day (d) or night (n) - type d or n:")
n = win.setBackground("MidnightBlue")
d = win.setBackground("DeepSkyBlue")
n_message = ("Time has been set to night!")
d_message = ("Time has been set to day!")
for character in range(1333):
  if userinput == n:
     print(n_message)
     win.setBackground("MidnightBlue")
     update(30)
     sun.undraw()
     moon = Circle(Point(100, 100), 90)
     moon.setFill("LightYellow")
     moon.draw(win)

     moon_cover = Circle(Point(140, 90), 60)
     moon_cover.setFill("MidnightBlue")
     moon_cover.setOutline("MidnightBlue")
     moon_cover.draw(win)
 else:
     print(d_message)
     update(30)
     win.setBackground("DeepSkyBlue")

     break
```

Comment: Try using `if userinput == 'n'` because `input()` returns strings.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!